# What do you think is the best first move in chess?

Tags: opening, online-chess, famous-moves

I'm new to chess and I want to ask you, what do you think is the best first move in chess? I know there is no fixed answer, I just wanted to ask for an opinion.

I will be very grateful for any answers.

Comment: Any answer you get is going to be opinion only. If there were, objectively, a best opening move, every grandmaster would play it every game, but this does not happen. There might, however, be a best first move for you, depending on your particular talents and temperament. Perhaps explain what draws you to the game. Why are you interested?

Comment: Voting to close based on what @PhilipRoe said. If there were an actual answer to this question, then everyone would be playing the best move on move 1. Since that is not the case, there is no true answer to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're new to chess, the best opening to help you learn and improve is 1.e4. There's nothing wrong with 1.d4 but it's a lot harder to learn for beginners.

Other moves like 1. c4, 1. Nf3 And 1. g3 are fine for experienced players but there are a lot of transpositions and beginners will miss most of what's going on.

When I teach chess, I recommend openings like the Bishop's and Vienna. These openings give white playable games and lead to the types of positions that make you better.

Answer (score 1):

Either 1. d4 or 1. e4. We don't know.

These two moves dominate elite human chess, and are also the choice of engines. For example, left to her own devices, Leela Chess Zero (in all her incarnations, with different nets, binaries, and such) will play one of these two moves. Same goes for all versions of Stockfish if you don't give Stockfish an opening book.

Do note that if chess is a draw (almost everyone thinks it is) then there is no "best move" because they all lead to at best draws anyway.

Comment: This is the only answer that seems to answer the question without adding opinion.  (+1)

Answer (score 0):

"first best move" is a very vague question, but e4 is the most common move and probably the best depending on your idea of how you want to develop your pieces

If your question is  "which opening is best", in which probably the [Vienna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vienna_Game) or [London system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_System) are both good and strong openings